# Article in front of abstract noun

Tags: definite-article, nouns

May I use definite article in front of abstract noun?

> 1.Creativity is a must in the present world.
>
> 2.**The** creativity of our boss has taken attention.

when and why I will use definite article?

Comment: Example 2 is probably better as “The creativity of our boss has **attracted attention**” or “**been noticed**”...

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty much the same rule for all nouns, abstract or concrete.  When referring to a general concept, either use no article or the indefinite article.  When referring to a specific or known instance of that concept, use the definite article.  This helps your audience know which you are talking about.

Example using a concrete plural noun:

> Pencils can be sharpened with a pencil sharpener, but **the pencils** used for drawing should be sharpened with a razor blade or penknife.

Same for abstract nouns:

> **Integrity** is normally a vital character trait for anyone in a position of trust, but **the integrity** of this well-known character seems deeply flawed, or even nonexistent.